# angular-ui/angular-google-maps cant set pushpin on a icon

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui, angular-google-maps

I'm working with angular-ui-google map..my task is to set a pushpin on the map..when ill do that a screen will pop up with the selected address so that i can proceed to the next step...the problem im facing is i cant seem to set pushpin on a specific icon on the map..for example i cant seem to set pushpin on Bangladsh Machine Tools Factory....any ideas how can i achieve this...TIA

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there is a boolean property called 'clickableIcons'in gmap in recent versions (after 3.X) ...setting it to false will do the trick